# Which sleep stage(s) account(s) for synaptic consolidation the most?

Tags: memory, neural-network, sleep, long-term-memory, hippocampus

I learnt that long-term consolidation of memories happens vastly while we are asleep, and it is accompanied by synaptic changes. But exactly which stage(s) of our sleep account for the synaptic consolidation the most?

Comment: Mind adding a reference to where you learned about this? Otherwise, good question!